# Accessing function parameters inside child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function

I have a piece of code that I am working on -

```
<ChildComponent OnSelect={() => this.changeEntity(index)} />
```

And I need to access the "index" value inside ChildComponent.

Comment: Please let us know if this is enough of a solution, or if you mean to somehow tell the ChildComponent what `index` is during the call to the OnSelect method. 
 `<ChildComponent OnSelect={() => this.changeEntity(index)} index={index} />`

Comment: The child component is a utility component so i did not to pass the index as props. I wanted to know if there was anything that could be done without passing it as prop

Comment: Why do you want to "access index inside ChildComponent ... without passing it as prop"?  The justification that it "is a utility component", doesn't really tell me exactly what you're trying to avoid by not passing it in as a prop.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to access the value of `index` then *pass that value*.

You can't pull it out of a function.

```
<ChildComponent index={index} OnSelect={() => this.changeEntity(index)} />
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming the ChildComponent itself has an index value independent of the parent component in which it's being rendered. In that case you can pass the function as a prop to child function

```
<ChildComponent OnSelect={this.changeEntity} />
```

In the child component:

```
constructor(props){
 //stores index maybe in the state     
 this.state = {
   index: 0 // or some other value
   ... 
 }
}

<SomeElement onSelect={() => this.props.changeEntity(index)} /> 
// here index is stored inside the ChildComponent independent of the parent component
```

I'm also assuming you're using react.

Comment: Actually the childcomponent is inside a forEach and the index of forEach is passed as index. So i need to pass the index.

Comment: yeah then you can just pass the index as a prop

Comment: I guess I will have to go with that now. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: if you're expecting a better solution, can you post the code and maybe we can find a good solution?